# Is there a way to know which chest holds the spell at the gambler?

Tags: has-been-heroes

When meeting with the spell gambler, is there a way to know which chest holds the spell?  I tried to follow the chests as they scrambled, but couldn't keep up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 40+ hours playing this game, I can pretty definitively say that it's random.  The animation of the chests "scrambling" is always exactly the same and is actually just them moving up and down in a circle (and it doesn't even end smoothly).  The end positions of the spell(s) or item(s) are random.

The best advice I can give for the gamblers is that there is a 2/3=66.6% chance that you **won't** get anything the first time, but a 2/3*1/3=2/9=22.2% chance that you won't get anything after two attempts which means there's a 77.7% chance that you **will** get at least something by the second try (which is a good enough deal for me).

If you're fine with those odds, then you should try for the spell/item if you like the first thing they show and you have enough gold for at least two attempts.